# Select ONLY the first level of components in the system and nor also the sub-componets

Tags: m2doc

in my Capella project I would like to select **only the first level** of the components of my System and not all the sub components.

I try this:

```
self.eAllContents (la::LogicalComponent).eContents (la::LogicalComponent)
```

But it select before the the first level of the components of my system but then select also all the sub-systems of the components of first level and I don't want this.

How can I do?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a more specific expression in this case:

```
selection.ownedArchitectures->filter(la::LogicalArchitecture).ownedLogicalComponentPkg.ownedLogicalComponents
```

This will list all LogicalComponent in the root LogicalComponentPkg.